# SQL - Package contains 2 objects with the duplicate name of

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I built this package in SSIS, but it is showing the following error code:
SQL - Package contains 2 objects with the duplicate name of Derived Column

Is there a way to correct this?

[image: Package]

Comment: Column, what you've added in "derived column" transformation, already exists in excel

Comment: Thank you Viktor. So, how do I remedy that

Comment: You must enter to the derived column transformation editor" (as I remember by right click on "derived column" transformation) and rename column name (for example add _1 in the end of the name)

Comment: Thank you. I changed the column names in the Derived Column Editor and it worked fine. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: Placed it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You must enter to the derived column transformation editor" (as I remember by right click on "derived column" transformation) and rename column name (for example add _1 in the end of the name)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the Output Name unique (highlighted below) in the Transformation Editor resolved the issue for me

[image]

**Note: I used a conditional split tool instead of derived/data conversion tool (as in your case)*